# I am trying to get all titles publishers and authors

Tags: sql

I am trying to get all titles publishers and authors that are from 'NY' but the titles table don't have a state column and I have to use `union/union all` to get it also need to have a column return in front of the data return to show what table it came from

```
select au_lname + ', ' + au_fname as name
from authors a
where state = 'NY'

union all

select pub_name
from publishers p
where state = 'NY'

union

select title_name
from titles
```

Comment: plz provide us with the structure of your table and tag the dbms you are using

Comment: Question is not clear.Give any sample data and expected result

Comment: This is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I got it to work for showing my names, publishers and titles that were published in NY. Still can't figure out how to do the table type  of author, publisher, and title in front of them like the problem.